# Oracle recursive query to get date range

Tags: sql, oracle, date, range

I need to use following query to get a date range

```
with DATETABLE (tempdate) AS
( 
SELECT trunc(to_date('2020-01-01 01:00:00','yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss')) AS tempdate from dual
UNION ALL 
SELECT tempdate + 1 FROM DATETABLE 
where tempdate < to_date('2020-02-01 01:00:00','yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss')
 )

select tempdate from DATETABLE
```

I got errors

```
ORA-01790: expression must have same datatype as corresponding expression
01790. 00000 -  "expression must have same datatype as corresponding expression"
*Cause:    
*Action:
Error at Line: 5 Column: 20
```

How to fix it?

Comment: What version of Oracle? Your query runs fine on Oracle 18c [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=e873197daa812647155dbc5cf0616847).

Answer (score 0):

On Oracle 18c, your query works without errors [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=e873197daa812647155dbc5cf0616847).

On 11g (and maybe other versions) there were issues with recursive queries and dates and you may be better recursing over numbers and then adding the value to the dates later:

```sql
WITH DATETABLE( tempdate ) AS ( 
  SELECT 0
  FROM   DUAL
UNION ALL 
  SELECT tempdate + 1
  FROM   DATETABLE 
  WHERE  DATE '2020-01-01' + tempdate + 1 <= DATE '2020-02-01'
)
SELECT DATE '2020-01-01' + tempdate AS tempdate
FROM   DATETABLE
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/2d700af/264/0)**:

```
|             TEMPDATE |
|----------------------|
| 2020-01-01T00:00:00Z |
| 2020-01-02T00:00:00Z |
| 2020-01-03T00:00:00Z |
  ...
| 2020-01-30T00:00:00Z |
| 2020-01-31T00:00:00Z |
| 2020-02-01T00:00:00Z |
```

Comment: Thanks MT0, it's amazing, you are right.
I write and test the query on 11g, it has errors as mentioned above.
on 12c, it doesn't has that errors.
Thanks again for your advice.

Answer (score 0):

This will work on all versions `11g` and above:

```
with t AS
( 
  SELECT DATE '2020-01-01' + level -1 AS tempdate from dual
  CONNECT BY LEVEL <= DATE '2020-02-01' - DATE '2020-01-01'
 )
SELECT tempdate FROM t;
```

Output:

```
TEMPDATE
--------
01-01-20
02-01-20
03-01-20
04-01-20
05-01-20
06-01-20
07-01-20
08-01-20
09-01-20
10-01-20
11-01-20
12-01-20
13-01-20
14-01-20
15-01-20
16-01-20
17-01-20
18-01-20
19-01-20
20-01-20
21-01-20
22-01-20
23-01-20
24-01-20
25-01-20
26-01-20
27-01-20
28-01-20
29-01-20
30-01-20
31-01-20

31 rows selected.
```

Comment: Thanks Lalit.I can't use connect by because need to make this query as compatible as possible with the Oracle and MSSQL environments.