# i want to create a temporary table in my oracle database which has only one column which displays date from 01-01-2003 till 01-01-2024

Tags: sql, oracle

How to create this table from dual, since I am not trying to select dates from any existing tables in database:

```
SELECT * 
FROM DUAL 
WHERE Date BETWEEN '2003-01-01' AND '2024-01-01'
```

I wrote the above and got this error:

> ORA-00936: missing expression

Comment: There are many articles that explain how to do this, for example https://blogs.oracle.com/sql/post/how-to-generate-days-weeks-or-months-between-two-dates-in-oracle-database. See https://dbfiddle.uk/MwbIAlB7

Comment: Or [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61234095/266304)?

Comment: dual is a table with a single column (named DUMMY)  and 1 row (value X). You can't put a where clause on it and hope it generates the rows for you...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SQL Server SELECT into existing table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4101739/sql-server-select-into-existing-table)

Answer (score 2):

Just how would you expect to have the DATE column in dual?
Here's how:

```
select date '2003-01-01'+level-1 cal_date
from dual
connect by level< (date '2024-01-01' - date '2003-01-01' )+1;
```